# Is it possible to expire redis increment by TTL

Tags: redis

I have a single number in redis which I want to increment counts of, however, I want each increment to expire and be removed after a TTL.

Essentially I want the behavior to be like so:

Time 1: Increment 5 (TTL 5), value is 5

Time 2: Increment 3 (TTL 5), value is 8

Time 6: Increment 5 expired, value becomes 3

Is this behavior possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you store in redis should be logs of operations. Then compute the final score with logs whose ttls are not reached.

Since you can

1. delete expired data more conveniently with sorted set,
2. get all live data faster with sorted set,

I would recommend using a sorted set like below:

1. use `Increment` as the main key
2. use timestamp of expiration time as the score in redis
3. use `[increment score]_[timestamp/uuid]` as a member in set

For example:
Suppose the times are:

```
Time1: 1696664893 (now)
Time2: 1696664894
Time6: 1696664898
Time7: 1696664899

zadd Increment 1696664898 5_sfdsafdsafdsa
zadd Increment 1696664899 3_fdafdsafdsfda
```

##### Get total score

Suppose it is Time 7 now

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE Increment 1696664899 +inf
# return 3_fdafdsafdsfda, split the string, get total score of 3
```

##### remove all expired data

```
ZREMRANGEBYSCORE Increment -inf 1696664898
```

Answer (score 0):

- You use `GET singleNumber`.
- If the key exists you set a new value with the response (e.g. 5), and the increment (e.g. 3) with `SET singleNumber 8 EX 5` where `EX 5` says that it will expire in 5 seconds.
- If the key didn't exist, you set a new value (e.g. 3) with `SET singleNumber 3 EX 5`.

If you don't want to reset the TTL with each increment, you could use `KEEPTTL` option for the [`SET` command](https://redis.io/commands/set/).